# How can I clear all the SAP GUI fields when I open a T-Code?

Tags: sap-gui

When I open a T-Code from SAP GUI, some of the fields are pre-populated from past queries. Is it possible to enter a T-Code and all the fields in the next window to be forced blank?

I develop scripts for SAP GUI and run into problems if fields already have content from prior queries.

Comment: What tcode you are talking about and what fields? Check your [user parameters](https://www.iup.edu/WorkArea/DownloadAsset.aspx?id=136583), those values could be pre-populated from there

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out. I know that some of the field values that are present when I open the T-Code are from prior queries run that day. I have researched similar situations and the overwhelming response is to clear the history, but it doesn't seem to be possible to do that from a script and when I do that, my ID from the login screen also get's cleared.

Comment: SAP history is nothing but the file `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\SAP\SAP GUI\History`, just delete this file and that's it

Comment: I agree that will work, but I'm trying to run from within Excel VBA. I also don't want to use my alphabet soup SAP id which I have never been able memorize. Also, other users of my Excel apps may not want their SAP history expunged. I just wish there was an SAP script command to clear all the fields in a T-Code form.

Answer (score 1):

The history cannot be disabled user-wise. Period.

Either all or nobody.

If you want to disable the history go to SAPgui options into *Local data* setting

[image]

The history in Windows is a simple Access MDB file but it is password-protected, so you may try to crack it and delete only your user lines but it is a bunch of work.

However, I guess the history that makes you crazy is not what I described above, but [SPA/GPA parameters](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abenmemory.htm#@@ITOC@@ABENMEMORY_4). Check it first

Answer (score 0):

You can empty some fields with :

> ""

```
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtRMMG1_REF-BWTAR").Text = ""
```

But doesn't work all the time...

Comment: that's what i do now but my wish list is to have on command that would clear all the fields on the T-Code data entry screen

Answer (score 0):

My method for this is to loop through all the fields (and recursively on all children elements) and set the text value of them to an empty string.

On read-only fields it throws an error and this is why "On Error Resume Next" is necessary.

```
Sub Start_Clearing()

'setup SAP
    If Not IsObject(SAPApplication) Then
       Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
       Set SAPApplication = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    End If
    If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
       Set Connection = SAPApplication.Children(0)
    End If
    If Not IsObject(Session) Then
       Set Session = Connection.Children(0)
    End If
    If IsObject(WScript) Then
       WScript.ConnectObject Session, "on"
       WScript.ConnectObject SAPApplication, "on"
    End If

    Dim UserArea As Object
    Set UserArea = Session.findByID("wnd[0]/usr")

    Clear_Fields UserArea

End Sub
'_______________________________

Sub Clear_Fields(Area As Object)
        
    Set SAPApplication = GetObject("SAPGUI").GetScriptingEngine
        
    Dim Obj As Object
    Dim NextArea As Object
    
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 0 To Area.Children.Count - 1
        
        Set Obj = Area.Children(CInt(i))
        
        If Obj.ContainerType = True Then
            If Obj.Children.Count > 0 Then
                Set NextArea = SAPApplication.findByID(Obj.ID)
                Clear_Fields NextArea
            End If
        End If
        
        Obj.Text = ""
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't wait to try this out!